# DataTables that have numbers followed by the percentage sign don't sort in order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables, rubygems

I have a rails 4.2 app with datatables installed from the [jquery datatables gem](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails). It all works fine but when the data has numbers followed by a percentage character it doesn't sort the column in the correct order. e.g.

rows with numbers of 11%, 9%, and 25% will sort as 11%, 25%, 9% instead of 25%, 11%, 9% as highest to lowest (take away the % character and they sort correctly).

I have found [this post on datatables](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/percent) but it says version 1.10+ should sort fine with percentages. That makes me think the gem uses a lower version. But they refer to version 1.10+ on the github page as if they are using a higher version than it.

Is the gem using a lower version than 1.10 or do I need to add some sort of tag to have percentage sorting work? I cant make sense of whats happening or what I need to do to make the sorting with percentages work

Comment: You can just look in the [source](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js).   So it uses v1.10.10

Comment: @j-dexx Thanks. I thought it would be burred in there somewhere deep or not mentioned in the files so I diddnt bother looking. I look silly now considering it has the version number right there.

Comment: depends how good the gem maintainer is.  Makes sense to leave it in the files.

Comment: The hidden columns that @power mentions can work, but using data-order would be a cleaner approach. The fact that your tables are user generated and therefore unpredictable, however, moots both solutions. You can try to get people to enter data without the %, resulting in a numeric (rather than the current lexical) sort, but you know how user training goes... Are there no constraints at all on what tables users can create?

Comment: @MarsAtomic Yes correct there is no restrictions to the tables they can make. On the DataTables site they say 1.10+ has percentage data type detection and sorting abilities built-in. Now that I know the gem is using 10.10.10 I'm wondering why those built in abilities aren't working. They don't mention adding a tag or plugin to make those built in abilities work.

Comment: I just [tested](http://pastebin.com/AEPGEQQ4) with the latest versions of DataTables and JQuery, and percentage sorting works without any additional modification. There has to be something specific to your code, so its probably time to lay your cards on the table so we can see what you have.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Sure. here is the gem line I use `gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', git: 'git://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails.git'` and here is a link to a page that has percentage data on a table https://guidir.com/guides/pokemon-go/pokemon/. Thanks for the help

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I thought it might have to do with the way you formatted the table cells, but that's not it. Can you create a SSCCE that reproduces the issue? Also, do you have a .js asset that you're using to provide a custom sort?

Comment: Thats frustrating. Did you use the same github gem and it worked fine with that? I can make an SSCCE but I do have a copy of the site on my local computer I can try strip away as much as i can and see if it changes. This is  in my js assets file `jQuery ->
  $('#example').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
    "sDom":"flrtip",
    bJQueryUI: true`

Comment: I found this https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20505/add-the-sign-percent-modify-sort with the same problem but they just update to 1.10 and it works fine for them

Comment: Just to confirm for you, I added a dummy table to a 4.2 app of mine and added a few <tr> worth of your data, and percentages sort fine. My gemfile uses `'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 3.3.0'` as specified in the install directions. Yours is different, but it *should* point to the latest version, directly from Github. The gem includes certain plugins, and who knows, maybe the old percentage plugin is included and is messing things up. Change your gemfile and see what happens.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Thanks. I made a test app and it also worked fine on that. Looks like the problem is on my end not the gems. Gonna have to dig deeper into my app to findout whats going on

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by creating the hidden column with the number and sort the actual column with the help of hidden column. Code looks like this.

```
$('table.subnets').dataTable({
  "aoColumns": [
      { "bSortable": true, "sType": "numeric", "iDataSort": 1 },
      { "bSortable": true, "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": false },
  ]
});
```

here first column is the column with "%" sign and column secont which is hidden is containing the numeric values. So the first column is sort with the help of hidden column. Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I should've mentioned the tables are generated by users. I don't know which columns will have percentage values in them or not and not all tables will have percentage values